# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working after upgrade to iOS8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have an iOS app with several UITableViews in them all of which worked as intended
. I upgrade the app to handle iOS8

since then I had a problem with loading a custom cell into the table view who's nib had the box in the ib checked 'use auto layout'. I then uncheck all of these on my custom cell and since then the cells of all my UITableViews not only don't call didSelectRowAtIndex path method but are not highlighted on touch.

I have check that all the cells are active by adding

```
if(cell.userInteractionEnabled){NSLog(@"is enabled");}else{NSLog(@"is not enabled");}
```

all of the loaded cells write 'is enabled' to the log

I am setting the delegate and data source via the ib in the storyboard and all of this was working prior to me changing the 'use auto layout' and upgrade to run on iOS 8.

what have i missed?

here is my code to create the cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCellWithNumberCellIdentifier";
    if( events.count>indexPath.row &&[[[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"tag"] integerValue] == -1)
    {
        EventsMonthSeparator *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
            cell = (EventsMonthSeparator *)[EventsMonthSeparator cellFromNibNamed:@"EventsMonthSeparator"];
            cell.date.text=[[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"date"];
            [Functions setFontFamily:@"Neutra Display" forView:cell andSubView:YES];
            if(cell.userInteractionEnabled){NSLog(@"is enabled");}else{NSLog(@"is not enabled");}
        }
        return cell;
    }else
    {
        eventsRow *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;
            cell = (eventsRow *)[eventsRow cellFromNibNamed:@"eventsRow"];
            cell.description.text=[[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
            cell.timedate.text=[[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"date"];
            cell.image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"tiledrinks"];
            cell.status.text=[Functions statusForIndex:[[[events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"booked"] intValue]];
            [Functions setFontFamily:@"Neutra Display" forView:cell andSubView:YES];
            cell.tag=1;
            [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
            if(cell.userInteractionEnabled){NSLog(@"is enabled");}else{NSLog(@"is not enabled");}
        }
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problem did you have loading the custom cell into the table view with auto layout turned on? It would be better to solve that problem, and keep using apt layout.

Comment: when it was turned on it worked perfectly

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please Do check that `Auto-Layout` is `OFF` (Non selected tickMark) in your Custom cell's `xib` Also.

And in Your `TableView` check this default setting,
As attached in below image [image]

I have same issue once, where I have give `NO Selection` in `selection` property of TableView's `attribute inspector`.

If you have done same then give `Single selection` there.

Hope this will help you !

Comment: hey man you saved my day... if the "selection = no selection" it wont call the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate.

Answer (score 2):

If you have selected auto layout, `cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;` will negate the auto layout that Xcode provides.
Also, could you check if all your tableViews' delegates are intact? If your delegate isn't set, the tapping on table view cell will not invoke the 'didSelectRow' method.

Comment: the deligates and datascource are set in the ib. the methods cellForRowAtIdexPath,willDisplayCell forRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath all work as normal

Comment: Just to check: Try putting a NSLog("Hello") in your didSelectRow method and comment out everything else.

Comment: FYI, you have put this line: `cell.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=NO;` ahead of reassigning the cell (`cell = ...`), so it will have no effect.  Try moving it lower.

Answer (score 1):

You can select "in single selection During Editing" in TableView, 
for example:
[image]